# Unable to run Jersey 2 Restful web service on Tomcat 9

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, tomcat9

I am writing a Jersey 2 Restful web service.
Here is the service class:

```java
package com.Test.PS;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;

import com.Test.Exchange.*; // Here class UserInfo is defined

@Path("/ps")
public class TestService {
    private UserInfo ui;
    public TestService () throws IOException {
        ui = new UserInfo();
    }
    public TestService (String uid) throws IOException {
        UserInfo ui = ObjectFileStore.serializeDataIn(uid);
    }

    public TestService (UserInfo ui) throws IOException {
        this.ui = ui;
        ObjectFileStore.serializeDataOut(ui);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHelloHTML(@QueryParam("uid") String uid) {     
        String resource="<h1> Hi '" + uid + "'. </h1>";
        return resource;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserInfo postNK(@QueryParam("asid") String asid, UserInfo u) {
        return ui;
    }
}
```

Here is the maven dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.27</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.27</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.27</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
  <version>2.27</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Finaly, this is my web.xml file:

```xml
  <display-name>Test-PS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test-PS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.Test.PS</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test-PS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am getting the following error when running this service on Tomcat 9 using url (http://localhost:8081/Test-PS/rest/ps?uid=90):

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message /Test-PS/rest/ps
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

On the console screen, I see:

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Test-PS] has started
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Test-PS] is completed
```

I tried adding several other dependencies as suggested by other posts here, however, still having the same issue. Surprisengly, sometimes it works for unknown reason!!!

I have also deleted all of the maven repositories, nothing has been changed!!!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is solved by:

- Deleting Eclipse and installing the EE version.
- Deleting Tomcat and installing 9.0.11 version.
- Recreating the project from the scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Use **jersey-container-servlet-core** instead of **jersey-container-servlet**

**Refer:**

Jersey dependecies - https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html

Tomcat versions compare - http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: You just saved me some headache!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from all your Jersey dependencies. You only use this when the server already has these jars in its library. Tomcat does not have the Jersey jars. If on the other hand you were using Glassfish, then you could use `provided`, as Glassfish already has all the Jersey jars.
2. Remove `Jersey-client` and `jersey-server` dependencies. They both are already pulled in by `jersey-container-servlet`. No need for the redundancy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply .. I tried that before, as I told in my question that I have tried several other dependencies combinations, still I am facing the same issue. However, I tried to maintain the jersey-container-servlet, javax.servlet-api, & jersey-hk2 dependencies only with the default compile scope as you have suggested. Still I am getting the same issue!!!

Comment: I have also tried jersey-container-servlet-core, same result. I am thinking of shiftting to glassfish. It seems that Jersey's 2 glassfish libraries are not compatable with Tomcat 9

Comment: what needs to be done if one wants to use different version of jersey(other than already present in Tomcat Server)? or it's not possible to use different version of jersey in existing Tomcat Server?